# Is it possible to obtain a 'relaxing lengths' for 8 node hexaedral element

Tags: finite-element, solid-mechanics

I am using 3D FEM with 8-node brick elements to model a certain type of growth/expansion, which is not a plastic deformation. First, I apply a pressure/load and I get displacement and the new position of nodes and calculate stress/strain. Next, I would like to change the 'edges' relaxing length (different edges by different factors) of an 8-node hexahedral element. Such change in relaxing length would be due to addition of a new material, resulting in expansion of a mesh.

My question is, whether in such a model I can calculate some sort of relaxing length for a brick element edges after application of pressure and consequently change it to get new nodal positions. I can imagine doing so for a 1D string, but I am not sure if it makes any sense for a 3D hexahedral element.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Do you have any schematics?